# Optimizing summary and other vector operations on subset in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a quite big table of data which consists of several categories.Names of categories are stored in list and each category has also multiple sub-categories, which are also stored in list and everything is stored inside pandas dataframe.
I would like to perform basic calculations, such as sum, max, and mean on this dataset when each time I filter the whole dataframe to sub-dataframe only with columns I need and then perfrom actions on it and store it inside dictonary. After it is done I construct dataframe from dict and merge two dataframes into one.
My code works but for big dataset and big list of categories is quite slow and I was wondering if there is more efficent way to do things.

This is what I wrote. (Actual list is different but the rule remains the same : each category is string and all sub-categories are category name + '.' + number)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import string
import time

categories = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
column_names = [letter + '.' + str(number) for letter in categories for number in range(10000)]
rand_matrix = np.random.rand(1000,len(column_names)).astype('float32')
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(rand_matrix, columns = column_names )

# calculate sum of by letter:

tic = time.perf_counter()  # start timer
func_dict = {}
for letter in categories:
    func_dict[letter + '.SUM'] = dataframe.loc[:, dataframe.columns.str.startswith(letter +'.')].sum(axis =1)
    func_dict[letter + '.MAX'] = dataframe.loc[:, dataframe.columns.str.startswith(letter +'.')].max(axis =1)
    func_dict[letter + '.AVG'] = dataframe.loc[:, dataframe.columns.str.startswith(letter +'.')].mean(axis =1)

funct_frame = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(func_dict)

final_frame = pd.concat((dataframe,funct_frame), axis =1)

toc = time.perf_counter()  # end timer

print(f'Load  and process data is : {toc - tic:0.4f} seconds')
```

and the output was:

```
Load  and process data is : 11.8811 seconds
```